# JAX-WS 2.1 - Why do I get a 'MessageCreationException' while trying to process my first web service request?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I am using JAX-WS 2.1 and I have built a web service using JAX-WS via the development tools in Netbeans 6.0.  It seems that everything builds correctly and starts correctly, however on the first web service request after restarting Tomcat, I get the following exception:

> SEVERE: Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: Unable to
> create StAX reader or writer
> com.sun.xml.ws.protocol.soap.MessageCreationException: Couldn't create
> SOAP message due to exception: Unable to create StAX reader or writer
> at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.decode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:365)
> at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.decodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:277)
> at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$500(HttpAdapter.java:93)
> at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:457)
> at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244)
> at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:135)
> at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:129)
> at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:160)
> at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:75)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
> at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:390)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)
> at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
> at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:283)
> at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:767)
> at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:697)
> at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:889)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

I imagine someone has seen this error before, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and why I am only getting it on the initial web service request?

Soap request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsd="ws.companynamehere.com/xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ns2="ws.companynamehere.com/xsd">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns2:Pickup>
        <contact>
            <company>DEMO COMPANY</company> 
            <name>DEMO COMPANY</name> 
            <phone>1111111111</phone> 
            <email>test@test.com</email> 
        </contact>
        <shipper>
            <shipperName>DEMO</shipperName>
            <address>123 TEST AVE</address> 
            <city>SOMEWHERE</city> 
            <state>SC</state> 
            <zip>99999</zip> 
            <pickupContactName>Test</pickupContactName> 
            <phone>9999999999</phone> 
            <email>test@test.com</email> 
            <email2 /> 
            <email3 /> 
            <fax  /> 
            <requestPickupDate>20101008</requestPickupDate> 
            <requestPickupTime>1200</requestPickupTime>  
        </shipper>
        <consignees>
            <Consignee>
                <name>TEST</name> 
                <destZip>99999</destZip> 
                <weight>1234</weight> 
                <pieces>1</pieces> 
                <pkgType>PL</pkgType> 
            </Consignee>
        </consignees>
    </ns2:Pickup>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Soap response (1st try only):

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
         <faultcode>S:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: Unable to create StAX reader or writer</faultstring>
      </S:Fault>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Comment: From the stack trace, there seems to be a problem with forming the SOAP response or with the SOAP request. Cant't you provide more info (code, wsdl)?

Comment: I can control the client and the server code (web service provider) via debugging and it seems I get this error before any of my code is executed on the server side.

Comment: @Josh:The soap response means that the SOAP request send by client could not be parsed and it is the client's fault. First of all I am not sure what you mean "1st try only". Is this exact request acceptable in later requests? The envelope seems well-formed. If there is no problem with xml (validate against wsdl) may be it is a networking issue? Do you have a low time-out in Tomcat?

Comment: I am using SoapUI to test and the first request fails, as in the first time I initiate the a request/response cycle it fails and then I can take the same request and initiate another cycle and I get a valid response.  I thought it could have been a timeout issue as well, so upped my timeout value to 60000 (60s) in my server.xml and it didn't help.

Comment: I can't find an issue with my request either, and I am thinking it may be some sort of marshalling error or something getting lost across the wire because the error appears in my Tomcat log on the server before a fault is returned.

Comment: @Josh:I googled on the exception and relevant posts mentioned, either the timeout in Tomcat or library conficts of parsers.Check the libraries used by Tomcat. Try deploying the web service via a jax.xml.Endpoint and test.If you get no problem with Endpoint then it is surely not a client error(despite the error fault reported that it is a client issue)

Comment: How to solve it? I also facing the same problem.